# Running LXC or Docker containers with a VServer container

Tags: docker, lxc, linux-vserver

Is it possible to run Docker or LXC containers within a Linux VServer container.

Does it require special kernel modules to be installed on the VServer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run Docker or LXC containers within a Linux VServer container?

I do not know.

If the required kernel features are available (see below), it may be possible. Both run in userland and use these kernel features to isolate processes.

> Does it require special kernel modules to be installed on the VServer?

No, neither LXC nor Docker require special kernel modules. However they use kernel features (CGroups, namespaces, …) which may or may not be there in a given kernel version.

- [LXC requires Linux >= 2.6.32, >= 3.8 for lxc-attach, >= 3.12 for unprivileged containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/getting-started/)
- [Docker requires Linux >= 3.10, recommends the latest version](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/)

If your kernel meets the requirements, give it a try. If it is too old, it depends:

- If your VServer installation is managed by yourself, it might be possible to upgrade to a sufficient version. However, everything newer than 2.6.22.19 is only available as Experimental Patches.
- If it is a hosted VServer, it depends on your hoster.

Comment: The experimental patches are here: http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org